# Skobbler maps annotations disappear after segue to different view controller then coming back

Tags: ios, skmaps

So we are using skobbler in downloaded offline mode and displaying annotations. When clicked, an annotation shows a callout and when the callout is clicked, the app segues to a detail view. When the user clicks back however the annotations disappear. I believe they still exist because when I call things like [skobblerMapView annotationForIdentifier:] it returns the annotation and also when I call [skobblerMapView showCalloutForAnnotation] it shows the correct callout.

Initially this doesn't happen and first one or two times I do it, the annotations are still there but if I segue and come back enough times (like two or three times) it begins to happen consistently.

In the meantime I've hacked it so that in my viewDidAppear I call clearAllAnnotations and readd all the annotations but it's not great. Any help on why this would be happening would be appreciated.

Also if any further info would be helpful to determining the cause please let me know too.

Comment: Can you reproduce the same behaviour in the demo app?

Comment: This is the expected behavior, because in the viewWillDisappear: method of the AnnotationsViewController/OverlaysViewController the annotations/overlays are removed. ([self.mapView clearAllAnnotations];, [self.mapView clearAllOverlays];).
By removing this method calls you will get the desired results.